# How to use replaceAll() in Javascript.........................?

Tags: javascript

I am using below code to replace , with \n\t

```
ss.replace(',','\n\t')
```

and i want to replace all the coma in string with \n so add this `ss.replaceAll(',','\n\t')` it din't work..........!

any idea how to get over........?

thank you.

Comment: One way can be you can extend String class in your app

`String.prototype.replaceAll = function(fromReplace, toReplace){
 return this.replace(new RegExp(fromReplace, 'ig'), toReplace);
}`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to do a global replace.  Unfortunately, you can't do this cross-browser with a string argument: you need a regex instead:

```
ss.replace(/,/g, '\n\t');
```

The `g` modifer makes the search global.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use regexp here. Please try following

```
ss.replace(/,/g,”\n\t”)
```

`g` means replace it globally.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another implementation of `replaceAll`.

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (stringToFind, stringToReplace) {
    if (stringToFind === stringToReplace) return this;
    var temp = this;
    var index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
    while (index != -1) {
        temp = temp.replace(stringToFind, stringToReplace);
        index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
    }
    return temp;
};
```

Then you can use it like:

```js
var myText = "My Name is George";                                            
var newText = myText.replaceAll("George", "Michael");
```

Comment: Thank you sir, have you compared the performance difference to Regex? I could not get Regex global replace working...

Comment: This will go into an infinite loop if the stringToFind includes part of the stringToReplace. Consider keeping a record of the current index (starting at -1) and have the while loop check if the next index is greater than the current index.